# Given that A, B, and C are pairwise independent, how to prove that they are mutually independent?

Tags: probability

Given **P(A) = 0.8, P(B) = 0.4, P(C) = 0.5, P(A U B U C)′= 0.04**
All events A, B and C are pairwise independent.

So far I have shown that A, B and C are mutually independent with the proof: Suppose A ∩ B and C are independent. P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(A ∩ B) *  P(C) = P(A) * P(B) * P(C) since P(A ∩ B) = P(A) * P(B)

How am I supposed to justify it using the figures shown at the top?

Comment: Looks like $P((A \cup B \cup C)') = P(A' \cap B' \cap C') = 0.04 \neq 0.06 = P(A')P(B')P(C')$, so they aren't mutually independent (since if they were, their complements would be). How can you tell that they're pair-wise independent given just those values?

Comment: Ah, did not see the apostrophe.

Comment: How do you get $P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A\cap B)*P(C)$?

Comment: @bof Supposing that they are independent.

Comment: Yes, but the assumption "$A\cap B)$ and $C$ are independent" is not one of the assumptions you stated. Are there any more hidden assumptions?

Comment: I had to solve P(A∪B∪C) which I got 0.6 and also P(A∩B∩C) previously.

Comment: How did you get $P(A\cup B\cup C)=0.6$?? Isn't $P(A\cup B\cup C)=1-P(A\cup B\cup C)'=1-0.04=0.96$??

Comment: $$0.96=P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A)P(B)-P(A)P(C)-P(B)P(C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)=0.8+0.4+0.5-0.32-0.40-0.20+P(A\cap B\cap C)=0.78+P(A\cap B\cap C$$ $$P(A\cap B\cap C)=0.96-0.78=0.18$$

Comment: (A∪B∪C)′ = A′∩B′∩C′ is 0.4, then P(A′∩B′∩C′) = 1 - (A∪B∪C) = 0.4 = 1 - (A∩B∩C), then P(A∪B∪C) = 0.6. Sorry I may have confused myself.

Comment: By 0.4 don't you mean 0.04?

Comment: Oh crap my bad, you're right.